# How to monitor a quartz scheduler job?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am very new to quartz scheduler. I am aware that we can enable logs for quartz jobs and triggers by doing the following configuration

```
org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.class: org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin
# Format of Log Generated
org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.jobSuccessMessage= Job [{1}.{0}] execution complete and reports: { 8 }
org.quartz.plugin.jobHistory.jobToBeFiredMessage= Job [{1}.{0}] to be fired by trigger [{4}.{3}], re-fire: { 7 }

org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.class= org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin
# Format of Log Generated
org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.triggerFiredMessage= Trigger \{1\}.\{0\} fired job \{6\}.\{5\} at: \{4, date, HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy\}
org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.triggerCompleteMessage= Trigger \{1\}.\{0\} completed firing job \{6\}.\{5\} at \{4, date, HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy\}
```

But I am trying to understand if there is any way to directly get the quantitative metrics like how many jobs are currently running or duration for each job etc.

I am also aware of various tools like quartz-dask which gives a ui for the said metrics. But I am more interested in the metrics which in turn I could push to my prometheus instance